# SSD showing up with over a dozen *tiny* fake disks in `diskutil list`

Tags: hard-drive, mac, partitioning, disk-utility, mac-pro

I bought [a new SSD](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Aura-for-Mac-Pro/) from Other World Computing. Unfortunately, now that I've got it installed, it's showing up as ***14*** individual disks, only one of which is actually of the advertised size:

[image]

Meanwhile, it shows up in the GUI Disk Utility as a single drive, as desired:

[image]

I can't think of a way to *wipe* the actual hardware, and reset how it appears to the OS; I can only reach individual disk-identifiers (`/dev/disk4`) with Disk Utility. I've already used the GUI Utility to re-partition it as a single, large empty space I don't know what else to do to clean this up.

Comment: It looks like you took these shots in Recovery mode, in which case these are various virtual disks used by recovery mode itself to fake up a usable OS X environment while running from a read-only disk image. On other words, they have nothing to do with the SSD. See [this previous answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22941/what-is-the-mac-os-x-base-system-disk-image-on-my-2011-macbook-air/23081#23081).

Comment: Ooo! That might be it. Post this as an actual answer, which will give me a chance to ‘accept’ it if I can later verify that?

Answer (score 0):

Those are not part of your disk. They are fragments of memory of 512KB used as additional virtual disks by the OS in order for it to have a form or disk write access without affecting your original disks. The 5MB one was initially created and it was not enough, so the smaller ones were added.

Comment: how do we remove them? Do we remove them after the OS is installed?

Comment: They should not exist anymore after the OS is properly installed.

Comment: Where are the virtual disks stored—in the BIOS/firmware or on the storage volume (SSD/HDD) ?